# Name conflicts when using Method extension and Inheritance

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I have an extension

```
fun Fragment.showToast(message: String, toastLength: Int = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) {
    Toast.makeText(context, message, toastLength).show()
}
```

In project we're using MVP:

```
interface MyContract {
    interface View {
        fun showToast(message: String)
    }
}

class MyFragment : Fragment(), MyContract.View {
    override fun showToast(message: String) {
        showToast(message)
    }
}
```

So in `MyFragment.showToast(message)` I expect to call extension function instead of `StackOverflowException`.

Is it possible to call extension function directly? Something like:

```
Fragment.showToast(this, message)
```

or I just need to give another name?

Comment: Try calling `this.showToast(message)` in overridden method in your fragment.

Comment: Still doesn't work. `this`, `this@MyFragment` are both references to `MyFragment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cast your MyFragment class to Fragment and do:

```kotlin
class MyFragment : Fragment(), MyContract.View {
    override fun showToast(message: String) {
        val fragment = this as Fragment
        fragment.showToast(message)
    }
}
```

This way you will refer to the extension function of the **Fragment** class

Answer (score 4):

Instance methods have precedence over extension functions, in case of signature conflict, so the behaviour you're experiencing is the expected one.

You can refer directly to *shadowed* extension function importing it with an alias: pretend you have a file `FragmentExt.kt` containing the extension method in a package named `mypkg`:

```
package mypkg

fun Fragment.showToast(message: String, toastLength: Int = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) {
    Toast.makeText(context, message, toastLength).show()
}
```

So, you can invoke extension function (avoiding to call instance method) as follows:

```
import mypkg.showToast as extShowToast
val fragment : Fragment = ...
fragment.extShowToast(message)
```

This approach works both in the `MyFragment` subclass and in any client class.

In Java code, you can do something similar by accessing Kotlin extension method as a static method on a class names by the file name: if your extension function is in `FragmentExt.kt`, Java code can point to extension method using `FragmentExtKt.showToats("Message here")`.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two methods that you can call on a `Fragment` instance with the exact same name and the parameters.

There's no way to distinguish which one you want to call.

I'd change the name of one.

E.g.

```
fun Fragment.toast(message: String, toastLength: Int = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) {
    Toast.makeText(context, message, toastLength).show()
}
```

Comment: you can distinguish between instance and extension method using an import with alias, as I showed in my response... I think this can solve the problem without renaming the extension function, as in your proposal...