# What do you do when Java and Kotlin methods collide?

Tags: java, kotlin, inheritance

I'm writing some Kotlin code using `jakarta-json-api`. The `JsonObject` class in that API extends `Map<String, JsonValue>`. When you use the class in Kotlin, that gives you access to the Kotlin `Map` methods like `[]`, `get`, and `getValue`.

Except, `JsonValue`, which `JsonObject` extends, also defines a `getValue(String)` method, where the `String` is a `JsonPointer`. So when I try to call `jsonObject.getValue(s)`, it's resolving to the `JsonValue` version of `getValue` instead of the `Map` version.

Other than casting `(jsonObject as Map<String, JsonValue>).getValue(s)` (which is pretty verbose), is there some way to convince the compiler to use the Kotlin method rather than the Java one?

Comment: Can't you write your own extension method that does the casting? Then, it won't be verbose.

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54746863/5133585) answer your question?

Comment: I'm a little confused about the hierarchy here.  Is `JsonObject` a class or an interface?  (The question calls it a class — but says that it extends, rather than implements, the `Map<…>` interface, and that it also extends `JsonValue`, whatever that is…)

Comment: @gidds Sorry. I was being slightly imprecise. Both `extends` and `implements` in Kotlin are represented in the same way, a colon. The issue is that it inherits two `getValue(String)` implementations and they do different things. I think this would be impossible in pure Java, but Kotlin adds a `getValue(String)` method to Java `Map`s that collides with the instance method.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, an import alias is the way to go. I originally didn't think this was an option because I couldn't import `getValue`. I thought it was because it was an instance method in Kotlin. Turns out it is an extension method, but I was importing it incorrectly. Thanks.